# Recompile java for tomcat7:run

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

Using `tomcat7:run` to run a web app, I've noticed that while the web contents are served directly from the file system, I'm unsure how to trigger a recompile of changes we make to java files.

Closing the server and rebooting works, but is there an automatic way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what is the parameter that is doing this work. This is my configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>${module.context.root}</path>
                <port>${module.listen.port}</port>
                <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.6</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

An it reloads the webapp immediately after I change some class. Be aware that such classes must be within the same module (i.e. the module with war packaging). The plugin is not able to detect any change that occurs outside (e.g. another dependent module / project)